# How to parse an array of string to a Json object?

Tags: node.js

I have a String array that i need to convert to JSON.

```
creators=["a","b","c","d"...."x"]
```

I want to convert to the following JSON format.

```
{
    "creators":[
        {"creator": "a"},
        {"creator": "b"},
        {"creator": "c"},
        ----------------,
        {"creator": "x"}
    ]
}
```

How can i implement this in Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
      var c=["a","b","c","d","x"]

          var obj = '{"creators":[' 
          for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
           obj += '{"creators" : "'+ c[i]+'"}'
           if(i != c.length-1){
           obj += ", ";
                }
           }
           obj += "]}";
    json = JSON.parse(obj)
   console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const creators=["a","b","c","d", "x"]

const object = {
  creators: creators.map(creator => ({ creator }))
                                    // ^^^ object property shorthand
                                    // { creator: creator }
};

console.log(object); // or JSON.stringify(object) if you need JSON
```

> It works fine if creators is an array, but sometimes creators just has
>   one element and i am getting creators.map is not a Function error.

If `creators` is not always an array, you can do the following:

```
creators = Array.isArray(creators) ? creators : [creators];
```

---

```
creators.map(creator => ({ creator }))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
creators.map(creator => {
   return { creator: creator };
})
```

Comment: It works fine if creators is an array, but sometimes creators just has one element and i am getting creators.map is not a Function error.

Comment: If it's an array with one element you wouldn't get that error, the problem is that it isn't an array, but a normal string. I will update my answer.

Comment: Check my update answer, but you should have said that `creators` is not always an array.